# Linq reducing one-to-many relationship to one-to-one

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

```
List<dynamic> a = new List<dynamic>();
a.Add(new { Foo = 1, Baz = "Inga", Name = "Alice"});
a.Add(new { Foo = 2, Baz = "Baz", Name = "Bob"});
a.Add(new { Foo = 3, Baz = "Hi", Name = "Charlie"});

List<dynamic> b = new List<dynamic>();
b.Add(new { Foo = 1, Value = "Bar", Code = "A"});
b.Add(new { Foo = 1, Value = "Quux", Code = "B"});
b.Add(new { Foo = 2, Value = "Bar", Code = "C"});
b.Add(new { Foo = 3, Value = "Mint", Code = "A"});
b.Add(new { Foo = 3, Value = "Seven", Code = "Q"});
b.Add(new { Foo = 3, Value = "Threeve", Code = "T"});
```

Ok....so I have a problem(*naturally*) 
This is contrived and simplified to focus on the problem at hand.
I need to modify a Linq query to project the two Lists to the following response:

```
[
   {  Foo = 1
    , Baz = "Inga"
    , Code = "A"
    , Bars = [{ Value = "Bar", Code = "A"}
             ,{ Value = "Quux", Code = "B"}
             ]
   }
   ,{  Foo = 2
     , Baz = "Baz"
     , Code = "C"
     , Bars = [{ Value = "Fizz", Code = "C"}]
    }
   ,{  Foo = 3
     , Baz = "Hi"
     , Code = "A"
     , Bars = [{ Value = "Mint", Code = "A"}
              ,{ Value = "Seven", Code = "Q"}
              ,{ Value = "Threeve", Code = "T"}
              ]
    }
]
```

## First, the TL;DR

> Is there any way to query collection b to select
>
> `(b.First Where Distinct By b.Foo)  AsEnumerable()` ?

### ...The long version

I need to select a projection of `a` but as it is being materialized, identify the first `Code` in list `b` where `b.Foo == a.Foo` and put `b.Code` directly on `a`. Then the items from b where `b.Foo == a.Foo` need to be put into `a.Bars`.

The problem I have on my hands is that I am not identifying a singular `a` so I can't preselect the `a` and `b` values to simplify this mess and there's no opportunity to remodel.

So, if I want to search `Where Value = Bar`;  Alice and Bob need to be returned with the proper mapping and projection.

The naive attempt would be...

```
var results = a.Join( b
              , master => master.Foo
              , detail => detail.Foo
              , (master, detail) => new { master, detail})
         .Select(item => new
         {
             item.master.Foo
           , item.master.Baz
           , item.master.Name
           , item.detail.Code
           , Bars = b.Select(x => x.Foo.Equals(item.master.Foo))
         };
```

but this causes my results to contain duplicate "Alice" records and duplicate "Charlie" records because it inner joined a and b.  What I really want to do (pseudo) is

```
a.Join(
        b.Where(b.Foo.Equals(a.Foo)).First()
        , master => master.Foo
        , detail => detail.Foo
        , (master, detail) => new { master, detail}
      )
 .Select(item => new
         {
             item.master.Foo
           , item.master.Baz
           , item.master.Name
           , item.detail.Code
           , Bars = b.Select(x => x.Foo.Equals(item.master.Foo))
         };
```

but no matter what I try, it comes out a mess.

> ...Note, I can't take the naive approach and then run a `DistinctBy` because the projection is anonymous.

Can anyone resolve this purely with Linq to Object queries? (Note: I'm not needing a single pass resolution)

Answer (score 2):

I would just stick with grouping the second group (denoted `b` here) and then using that paired with a find to compose the projection.

```
var results = b.GroupBy( d => d.Foo ).Select( g => new {
    Foo = g.Key,
    Baz = a.First( i => i.Foo == g.Key ).Baz,
    Code = g.First().Code,
    Bars = g.Select( e => new { Value = e.Value, Code = e.Code }).ToArray()
});
```

[image]

Comment: If you make a `Dictionary<int, string>` (Foo -> Baz) from `a` beforehand, and use that instead of `a.First( i => i.Foo == g.Key).Baz`, I think it will perform even faster than `GroupJoin`. Good answer +1

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the `Code` in a single result entry is just the `Code` of the first joined `b` element.

So try this:

```
var result = a.GroupJoin(b,
                         a0 => a0.Foo,
                         b0 => b0.Foo,
                         (a0, bs) =>
                             new
                             {
                                 Foo = a0.Foo,
                                 Baz = a0.Baz,
                                 Code = bs.Select(b1 => b1.Code).FirstOrDefault(),
                                 Bars = bs.Select(b1 => new {b1.Value, b1.Code}).ToArray()
                             }).ToArray();
```

Comment: I was thinking your approach seems promising, but...
`A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree`

Comment: I'm not getting that error. It runs smoothly. Tested both with classes and with `dynamic`. Are you using this with `EntityFramework` or something? I was assuming `a` and `b` are already populated.

Comment: I've updated the answer so it might suits your situation now.

Comment: actually, you're spot on (about EF -currently adapting your changes to my RWS to see if it fits) I'm sorry for excluding that.  I'm using Entity Framework for its ADO.NET generators to hydrate from a database view. I posed the scenario as Linq to Objects to simplify the problem, but I forgot that "little detail."

Comment: ok.So in one of my attempts prior to making my post,I had tried to do a GroupJoin.I abandoned it because of the following piece of complexity that I factored out for my simplification:The caller needs to be able to query for the whole thing based on`Bar.Value`but the list of`Bars`that gets returned needs to be for "all b where a.Foo == b.Foo" I sort of touched on this when I mentioned the problem related to my query looking to return a set.I need to be able to search for `a` where applicable,`b`where applicable,grab all`b`for each identified`a`and then project the whole thing.There's the rub.

Answer (score 0):

[GroupJoin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you need here. You can think of `Join` like `SelectMany` while `GroupJoin` - like `Select`. The difference is the type of the second argument of the projection - `TInner` for `Join` and `IEnumerable<TInner>` for `GroupJoin`. In LINQ syntax the `GroupJoin` is achieved by `into` clause.

With all that being said, here is how it looks for your example in both syntaxes:

```
var resultsA = a.GroupJoin(b, master => master.Foo, detail => detail.Foo, (master, details) => new
{
    master.Foo,
    master.Baz,
    master.Name,
    Code = details.Select(detail => detail.Code).First(),
    Bars = details.Select(detail => new { detail.Value, detail.Code })
});

var resultsB =
    from master in a
    join detail in b on master.Foo equals detail.Foo into details
    select new
    {
        master.Foo,
        master.Baz,
        master.Name,
        Code = details.Select(detail => detail.Code).First(),
        Bars = details.Select(detail => new { detail.Value, detail.Code })
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from ai in a
            let bs = b.Where(bi => bi.Foo == ai.Foo)
            select new
            {
                ai.Foo,
                ai.Baz,
                Code = bs.Select(bi => bi.Code).FirstOrDefault(),
                Bars = bs.Select(bi => new { bi.Value, bi.Code }),
            };
```